# How to create an Amazon AMI with HVM from scratch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, virtualization

All the instructions I find online start with an existing AMI, but I would like to create an AMI from scratch using HVM instead of PV.

Does anyone know the procedure for doing this?

Comment: Can you explain what PV is ?

Comment: Currently in the process of doing this. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score -2):

The procedure is virtually identical, start with an HVM AMI, make your changes, use the CreateImage API call.  If we refer to the Instance Type Matrix (http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/), we can see HVM is the dominant virtualization style at this point in time for EC2.

Comment: OP explicitly asks how to create an AMI *from scratch*.